# Why React detect the function reference as new?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, dispatch

I have theorical question about custom hooks and use effect when redux is involved.
Let`s assume I have this code:

```
//MyComponent.ts
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const MyComponentBase = ({fetchData, data}) => {
   React.useEffect(() => {
      fetchData();
   }, [fetchData]);

   return <div>{data?.name}</data>
}
const mapStateToProps= state => {
   return {
       data: dataSelectors.data(state)
   }
}

const mapDispatchToProps= {
    fetchData: dataActions.fetchData
}

export const MyComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponentBase);
```

This works as expected, when the component renders it does an async request to the server to fetch the data (using redux-thunk). It initializes the state in the reduces, and rerender the component.

However we are in the middle of a migration to move this code to hooks. Se we refactor this code a little bit:

```
//MyHook.ts
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {fetchDataAction} from './actions.ts';

const dataState = (state) => state.data;
export const useDataSelectors = () => {
   return useSelector(dataState);
}

export const useDataActions = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   return {
      fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchDataAction)
   };
};

//MyComponent.ts
export const MyComponent = () => {
   const data = useDataSelectors()>
   const {fetchData} = useDataActions();

   React.useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
   }, [fetchData]);

  return <div>{data?.name}</data>
}
```

With this change the component enters in an infite loop. When it renders for the first time, it fetches data. When the data arrives, it updates the store and rerender the component. However in this rerender, the `useEffect` says that the reference for `fetchData` has changed, and does the fetch again, causing an infinite loop.

But I don't understand why the reference it's different, that hooks are defined outside the scope of the component, they are not removed from the dom or whateverm so their references should keep the same on each render cycle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useDataActions` is a hook, but it is returning a new object instance all the time

```
return {
  fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchDataAction)
};
```

Even though `fetchData` is most likely the same object, you are wrapping it in a new object.

You could `useState` or `useMemo` to handle this.

```
export const useDataActions = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const [dataActions, setDataActions] = useState({})

   useEffect(() => {
     setDataActions({
      fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchDataAction)
     })
   }, [dispatch]);

   return dataActions;
};
```

Comment: Completely right. I didn't notice it :facepalm: Thanks for the help

Comment: "Even though fetchData is most likely the same object" - it's not, it is a new arrow function each time. This is the real problem - the object returned by `useDataActions` can be recreated, since it is not used as-is, only deconstructed; but the value of `object.fetchData` must be memoized.

Comment: @Cerberus you are right. The return object and the fetchData key are new. That;s why a useEffect fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

first of all if you want the problem goes away you have a few options:

1. make your `fetchData` function memoized using `useCallback` hook
2. don't use `fetchData` in your `useEffect` dependencies because you don't want it. you only need to call `fetchData` when the component mounts.

so here is the above changes:
`1`

```
export const useDataActions = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const fetchData = useCallback(() => dispatch(fetchDataAction), []);

   return {
      fetchData
   };
};
```

the `2`nd approach is:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
   const data = useDataSelectors()>
   const {fetchData} = useDataActions();

   React.useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
   }, []);

  return <div>{data?.name}</data>
}
```

Comment: Completely right. I didn't thougt about the useCallback. I don't know if it would be a better approach the `useCallback` or the `useMemo` from @radudiță response. But both seems valid approaches. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk Cheers